# Remove a problematic bathroom thumb lock

Tags: lock, bathroom-fixtures, joinery

I have a broken door lock mechanism that needs replacing so I removed the door handles on both sides and moved on to the thumblock but I could not find the expect allen key fitting that normally holds these in place. Now looking at each side I can't see a way of removing either side to get to the screw covers to pop it off as normal.

Any idea how to get the thumb and safety off to get at the screw plate with no allen key present on either?

[image: Safety lock]

As you can see the screw cover won't come off over the top and I can't see how to get the safety off or the thumb either.

[image: Thumb]

Comment: A side view may be helpful , look for a set screw on one of those knobs. Since the one has a slot it may unscrew from the other if there are no set screws.

Comment: The one with the slot is the safety on the outside. No set screws and I have tried unscrewing, pulling doesn't seem to do much either.

Comment: I might try driving a crow bar / wonder bar under the handle and prying it apart, The problem with this method is it will crush the bolt cover and may damage the door, I have not had a mechanism that did not have some kind of screw or release the release can just be a bump usually on the inside handle when pushed in the handle can slide off. Good luck.

Comment: Since you're replacing it, I'd try vice-grips on both sides and rotate until something breaks. Maybe then you will be able to get to the internals and remove it.